# add div based on value in number input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number fields, each with a class "product-quantity", and a set of empty divs. the number fields are set with a data-attr small, medium, and goes up to 5xl. The empty div's are set with a data-attr small, medium, and goes up to 5xl as well because the small number field is associated with the small div and so one.

When you increase or decrease the number inside the small number field a div "small" should insert after the empty div with the attr small.

When you increase or decrease the number inside the medium number field a div "medium" should insert after the empty div with the attr medium.... and so on

additionally, all of the above belongs to a product x container, and there are multiple products on a page.

I have this jsfiddle that simulates what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/25/

however, right now when I add/subtract a number to the small number fields, it adds/subtracts a div to both the empty small/ medium div as well as in both products. and same for the medium.

I am having a hard time trying to associate which number field belongs to which empty div, which belongs to which product.

html:

```
<div id="product-1">    
   <div class="size-field">

      <div id="size-label">
      s
      </div>
         <div class="number-input">
             <input id="Small" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Small" min="0" 
             max="9999" data-product-id="1">
             </input>
         </div>
   </div>
      <div id="size-label">
      m
      </div>
         <div class="number-input">
            <input id="Medium" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Medium" 
            min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="1">
            </input>
         </div>

     <div class="name-number-header"><h5>HEADER<h5></div>
         <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">small:
         </div>
         <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Medium">medium:
         </div>
    </div>

<br clear="all">

<div id="product-2">    
   <div class="size-field">

      <div id="size-label">
      s
      </div>
         <div class="number-input">
             <input id="Small" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Small" min="0" 
             max="9999" data-product-id="2">
             </input>
         </div>
   </div>
      <div id="size-label">
      m
      </div>
         <div class="number-input">
            <input id="Medium" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Medium" 
            min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="2">
            </input>
         </div>

     <div class="name-number-header"><h5>HEADER<h5></div>
         <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">small:
         </div>
         <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Medium">medium:
         </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
    $('.name-number-field').remove();
        var val = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++){
        $('<div/>',{'class':'name-number-field'}).insertAfter($("[data-size]"));
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to start with closing the H5 tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-size="'+this.name+'"]');

    ele.nextUntil('[data-size]').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++) {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'name-number-field'
        }).insertAfter(ele);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/30/)

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, what you're really trying to do is just add one if the value increments, and remove the last if the value decrements, and for that the approach would be somewhat different:

```
$('.product-quantity').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        old = $(this).data('val'),
        ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-size="'+this.name+'"]'),
        inc = val >= old;

    if (inc) {
        $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'name-number-field'
        }).insertAfter(ele);
    }else {
        $('.name-number-field', ele.parent()).last().remove();
    }

    $(this).data('val', this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/38/)

Comment: this is very close, however it doesn't remove them when a number is subtracted

Comment: oh I moved the remove argument up a line and it works!

Comment: It does, did you try the fiddle, should be working ?

Comment: does ele.nextUntil remove the first or last red div or is it random? I would like it to remove the last one

Comment: It removes all of them, and runs the loop again, inserting them all over again. That was how you where doing it, so I assumed that was how you wanted it.

Comment: oh no! I only want to remove the last div that is added because there will be information in those red divs

Comment: @anmaree - Okay, added a solution for that as well.

Comment: thank you so much. one more quick question- when I try to replace the selector $('<div/>', {'id': 'name-number-field'}) with say some simple html such as '<p>hi</p>' it breaks. why is that?

Comment: i am able to add text to the div that is added, but once I add text to it, it wont remove it. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Make Use of your `data-product-id` and hook the textbox's parent and target the required elements.

Try this,

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
    $('.name-number-field').remove();
            var val = $(this).val();

    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++){
        $('<div/>',{'class':'name-number-field'})
        .insertAfter($(this).parents('#product-' + $(this).data('product-id')).find("[data-size]"));
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/36/)

Edit:

```
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
    $('.name-number-field').remove();
            var val = $(this).val();

    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(val); i++){
        $('<div/>',{'class':'name-number-field'})
        .insertAfter($(this).parents('#product-' + $(this).data('product-id')).find("[data-size='"+ $(this).attr('name') +"'][data-size]"));
    }
});
```

### [NEW - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7PhJZ/37/)

Comment: the small number field adds a div after the small empty div and the medium empty div. the small number field needs to associate with just the small empty div and the medium number field needs to associate with the medium empty div